# Как показать элементы которые помещаются на ширину экрана?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Есть динамические элементы, которые могут быть разные по ширине.

Каким образом,отобразить количество элементов на всю ширину экрана,не меняя ширину элемента(т.е вес не подходит).

Не исключаю использование Recycler View,можно привести пример на данной вью внутри которого есть динамические элементы( в данном случае recycler view не должен скроллится и элементы не должны выходить за пределы экрана)

Answer (score 0):

Я вам могу предложить самое простое решение вашей проблемы - использование `RecyclerView` и элементами списка у которых есть кастомно созданная разметка. В чем суть данного решения - вы сможете отобразить нужное вам кол-во элементов у каждого из которых будет свой размер и не нужно будет прописывать для каждого пункта списка свой размер. Просто когда будете создавать разметку для вашего пункта списка укажите ширину/высоту `wrap_content`. В сети очень много туториалов по созданию своих списков, [вот](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) например есть инструкция. На мой чисто субъективный взгляд RecyclerView вам поможет :) Если возникнут сложности или будет что-то непонятно - пишите, постараемся помочь :)

Comment: Если я передаю 10 элементов в список. Как мне отобразить только те,которые вмещаются на экран?

Comment: не очень понял)) у вас 10 элементов, что дальше делается я как-то не понял)) вы все сразу показать не сможете если что

Comment: у меня задача  - просто заполнить всю ширину экрана возможным количеством элементов без урезания их размера.)

Comment: Вот у меня 10 элементов,если они все маленькие и помещаются на экран - отобразить их все. Если помещаются только 5 - то отобразить только 5 )

Comment: ну так используйте RV и все)) в чем проблема? поставьте тег в xml и будет вам счастье) ничего не урезается и будет показывать столько элементов сколько экран позволяет

Comment: RV скроллится) А если мы запретим scroll, то может быть такое,что какой-то элемент зайдет за ширину экрана))

Comment: может показываться кусок наверное, но зачем запрещать скролл в списке?)

Comment: Потому что задача стоит изначально не в списке. А в том,чтобы можно было показать максимально количество элементов без обрезки) В вопросе про скролл не слова))

Comment: ну логика я думаю в том чтобы отобразить самое большее кол-во элементов, то как вы это задание будете делать не важно, можете так же использовать gridView для таких целей, там будет типа табличка получаться, и за скролл тоже можно особо не переживать, за него ведь ничего не сказано)

Comment: Скроллиться не должно)
А вообще интересно,можно ли как-нибудь ограничить показ элементов в RV(которые выходят за экран) , я что-то гуглил, не нашел)

Comment: Все элементы разного размера?

Comment: Если элементов больше чем умещается на экране то они должны сносится на новую строку?

Comment: @LeonidAltshooler разного, не должны. Они должны просто не показываться(вместо переноса на новую строку)

Comment: А как вам удобнее прямо через xml или через RecyclerView?